# Git Error: RPC failed; HTTP 400 curl 22 The requested URL returned error: 400

Tags: git, github, repository, push, commit

```
git push -u origin main
```

> error: RPC failed; HTTP 400 curl 22 The requested URL returned error:
> 400
>
> send-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
>
> fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly

Everything up-to-date

i tried,
`git config http.postBuffer 524288000` but it didn't worked

Comment: Please edit your question to include `git config -l --show-origin` as a code block (not an image).  Also, the [Git FAQ](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#http-postbuffer) is clear that `http.postBuffer` should not be used in normal circumstances and usually only serves to waste memory.

Comment: What's the output of `GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 git push -u origin main`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow few steps:

1. Since Git LFS 2.2.0 you can use git lfs migrate command. In your case it would look this way:

`git lfs migrate import --include="*.csv"`

2. When pushing a large amount of data (initial push of a big repository, change with very big file(s)) may require a higher http.postBuffer setting on your git client (not the server). Increase the Git buffer size to the largest individual file size of your repo:

`git config --global http.postBuffer 524288000`

3. Push your code in origin/relevant branch:

`git push -u origin main`

After this, you should be able to push changes into origin branch.